If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$ and exists $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{1}{f'(x)}$, there is an interval centered at $a$ with $f(x)\neq0$ for any $x\neq a$ in it

Suppose that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=0$ and exists $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{1}{f'(x)}$ show that there exists an interval with center in $a$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ for any $x \neq a$ in the interval.

By the hypothesis we know that given $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta_1, \delta_2$ s.t. if $|x-a| < \delta_1$ then $|f(x)| < \varepsilon$ and if $|x-a|<\delta_2$ then $|\frac{1}{f'(x)}-L| < \varepsilon$, i try to use $\delta:=\min \{\delta_1, \delta_2 \}$ and show that $(a-\delta , a+\delta)$ is the desired interval, but i cant conclude these by using the inequalities $|f(x)| < \varepsilon$ $|x-a|<\delta_2$ then $|\frac{1}{f'(x)}-L| < \varepsilon$, maybe if a take a special $\varepsilon$ i can conclude, but i not sure.
Any hint or help i will be very grateful.

What you wrote with $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ is true. However, in this case, I'd to first look for what I want to conclude from each of the hypotheses. To that end, I'd draw a picture (see below), from which we see $f$ must cross the $x$-axis at $x=a$ by the first hypothesis. The second hypothesis ensures the derivative is nonzero at $x=a$. So, I think about what theorems I have available for relating derivative and function values. The first that came to my mind is the mean value theorem, which I use below. Also, it is worth noting that here we can pick $\varepsilon$ to be a specific value that is suitable for obtaining the desired inequalities; specifically, here is chose $\varepsilon = 1/2|L|$.
Note: Although not explicitly stated in the given prompt, I assume below that $f$ is differentiable around $a$.
Proof: We proceed by showing $f(a) = 0$ (Step 1), $f'$ is nonzero in a neighborhood of $a$ (Step 2), and then that this implies $f(x) \neq 0$ for $x\neq a$ in this neighborhood (Step 3).
Step 1.
Because $f$ is differentiable at $a$, it is also continuous at $a$. Thus,
$$f(a) = \lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = 0.$$
Step 2.
Let $L$ denote the limit in the second hypothesis, and note $L\neq 0$ since $1/f'(x)$ cannot equal zero.
By this hypothesis, there is $\delta > 0$ such that
$$ | x - a| \leq \delta \quad\implies \quad \left| f'(x)- \frac{1}{L} \right| \leq \frac{1}{2|L|}
\quad\implies\quad  \frac{1}{|L|}-|f'(x)|\leq \frac{1}{2|L|},$$
where the final inequality is an application of the reverse triangle inequality. Rearraning reveals
$$ |x-a|\leq\varepsilon \quad\implies\quad 0 < \frac{1}{2|L|} \leq |f'(x)|,$$
and so $f'$ is nonzero for all $x \in [a-\delta,a+\delta]$.
Step 3.
Consider any $x \in [a-\delta,a) \cup (a, a+\delta]$. By the mean value theorem, there is $\xi_x$ between $x$ and $a$ such that
$$ f(x) - f(a) = f'(\xi_x) (x-a).$$
By the results above, $f(a) = 0$ and $f'(\xi_x) \neq 0$ (n.b. $\xi \in [a-\delta,a+\delta]$ since it is between $x$ and $a$). Thus,
$$ f(x) = f(x) - f(a) = \underbrace{f'(\xi_x)}_{\neq 0} \underbrace{(x-a)}_{\neq 0} \neq 0.$$
Because $x$ was arbitrarily chosen in $[a-\delta,a) \cup (a,a+\delta]$, the result follows. $\blacksquare$
A diagram for this problem is provided below.


Oh I can understand your explanation, i only have one question: It is necessary to take  $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2|L|}$?   thank you very much for taking the time to make this beautiful explanation

Sure thing, happy to help. Nah, it wasn't necessary. The key thing I needed for this was argument to work was to get $1/|L| - \varepsilon > 0$, and so I could have used, for example, $\varepsilon = 1/3|L|$.
Generally, I usually pick $\varepsilon$ to be "half the distance" to whatever I'm interested in. In this case, it was the distance from $0$ to $1/|L|$.

Suppose there is a sequence $(x_n)$ of distinct numbers  tending to $a$ such that  $f(x_n)=0$ for all $n$. Then, for $n \neq m$,  $0=f(x_n)-f(x_m)=f'(t_n)(x_n-x_m)$ for some $t_n$ between $x_n$ and $x_m$. But then $f'(t_n)=0$ and $t_n \to a$ This contradicts the hypothesis. Can you finish?

$x_n \to a$ and this implies $t_n \to a$ as $n,m \to \infty$. @TedShifrin

Yes, of course.

Nice and very slick argument. +1

You can define $f(a) =0$ without affecting any of the hypoyheses and since $1/f'$ has a limit the derivative $f'$ is non-zero around $a$. By Darboux property it maintains fixed sign on each side of $a$ and hence $f$ is strictly monotone on each side of $a$. Since $f(a) =0$ it follows that $f$ is non-zero on both sides of $a$.
